# MySQL: Adding Calculated Column with IF ELSEIF

Tags: mysql, ddl, calculated-columns

I'm struggling with an Alter Table scenario.
I have a table "example" with columns 1 to 3 existing. I want to add a column "destination" which than should contain either a value from column2 or from column3 depending on column1.
I tried the following code but it throws errors at the first line of the IF statement. Error is with the column1 reference, it is expecting an opening parenthesis but when I put the IF clause' condition in parantheses, it is rejecting the THEN function.
MySQL 8.0
See code below. Who can help? Many thanks,
Thomas

```
ADD COLUMN
(
Destination VARCHAR(15) 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
    (
    IF column1 = "north" THEN
        SET destination = column2
    ELSEIF column1 = "south" THEN   
        SET destination = column3
    ELSE
        SET destination = ""
    END IF
    )
STORED
)
;
```

Comment: You can't have a `SET` statement inside an `ADD COLUMN` statement.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following syntax( *containing `CASE..WHEN..ELSE` Statement instead of `IF..THEN..ELSE`* ) of Generated Column which's released in DB version 5.7+ :

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD COLUMN
(
Destination VARCHAR(15) 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
    (
    CASE WHEN column1 = "north" THEN
           column2
         WHEN column1 = "south" THEN   
           column3    
    END 
    )
STORED
)
```

without assignment to the derived column itself and without `set` clause.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ef70b6e9b290c2b6a128875b8dc4db26)</kbd>

Comment: Hi Barbaros, many thanks. Problem is that with this code, the system does not recognise "column2" and errors out. Is some select statement required?

Comment: you're welcome @thomasnngooglemailcom . Those columns `column1, column2 and column3` should already exist within the table before issuing the alter statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot, first answer already worked, I had a typo. Sorry for that,brgds Thomas